# How to display date in next page?

Tags: php

I really need some help about how to pass returndate value in next page(save.php). the value that i cant' pass was under this "(input type='hidden' name='retDate[$i]' value='$retDate')". 
I'm using calendar datepicker at this website(http://www.triconsole.com/php/calendar_datepicker.php). Appreciate if someone can help me about this and do refer below for my coding.

under "result.php"

```
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></br>
    <h1>RESULT </h1>
    <p><b>Escalation Date : </b>
    <?php echo $_POST["date1"] ?> until <?php echo $_POST["date2"] ?>
    </p>
    <?php 
                 ......
            //Select database
            $selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $link)
            or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");

            //declare the SQL statement that will query the database
            $query = "SELECT....."; 

        //execute the SQL query and return records
        if ($result = mssql_query($query, $link)){
            echo "<form name='form1' method='post' action='save.php'>";
            echo "<table border='1'>
            <tr>
            <th>batch_exception_id</th>
            <th>batch_id</th>
            <th>process_date_time</th>
            <th>Return Date</th>
            </tr>";
            $i=0;
            while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
                $rDate = $row['ReturnDate'];
                $beID = $row['batch_exception_id'];                         
                $proc_dt = $row['process_date_time'];
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $beID . "<input type='hidden' name='beID[$i]' value='$beID'/></td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['batch_id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $proc_dt . "<input type='hidden' name='procDT[$i]' value='$proc_dt'/></td>";

                if($rDate == ""){
                    echo "<td>";    
                            $f_name="retDate[".$i."]";    
                    $myCalendar = new tc_calendar($f_name, true, false);      
                    $myCalendar->setIcon("calendar/images/iconCalendar.gif");     
                    $myCalendar->setDate(date('d'), date('m'), date('Y'));    
                    $myCalendar->setPath("calendar/");    
                    $myCalendar->setYearInterval(2000, 2020);     
                    $myCalendar->dateAllow('2000-01-01', '2020-01-01');   
                    $myCalendar->setDateFormat('j F Y');      
                    $myCalendar->setAlignment('left', 'bottom');      
                    //$myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("", "0", "0"), 0, 'year');   
                    //$myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("0", "0"), 0, 'month');      
                    //$myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array("0"), 0, '');    
                    $myCalendar->writeScript();
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='retDate[$i]' value='$retDate'/>";
                    //echo "<input type='hidden' name='retDate[$i]' value='".$myCalendar->getDate()."'/>";    
                    $i++;       
                    echo "</td>";
                } else {
                    echo "<td>" . $rDate . "</td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";       
            }           

            echo "</table><br/>";
            echo "<input type='button' value='<<' onclick='history.back(-1)'/>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='total_rec' value='$i'/>";          
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Save'/>";         
            echo "<input type='button' value='Print' onclick='window.print()'/>";
            echo"</form>";
        }

        //close the connection
        mssql_close($link);     
    ?><br/>                 
</body>
```

[image]

under "save.php"

```
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"></br>       
    <?php 
        //$ReturnDate = $_POST["rDate"];
        $arrbeID = $_POST["beID"];
        $tot_rec = $_POST["total_rec"];
        $arrprocDT = $_POST["procDT"]; 
        $arrretDate = $_POST["retDate"]; 

        for ($i=0; $i<$tot_rec;$i++) {
            echo "Batch Esc. ID: ".$arrbeID[$i]." 
                | Proc. DateTime: ".$arrprocDT[$i]."
                | Ret. Date: ".$arrretDate[$i]."
                <br>";
        }       

    ?><br/>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: use **print_r($_POST);** in your save.php & check what data you are getting here.

Comment: Hi sumant thank for the suggestion. I did it and it's display as below:... [retDate] => Array ( [0] => 1000 [1] => 1000 [2] => 1000 [3] => 1000 [4] => 1000 [5] => 1000 [6] => 1000 [7] => 1000 [8] => 1000 [9] => 1000 [10] => 1000 [11] => )

Comment: Is it the data you are posting from your 1st page? Coz whatever data you are posting from 1st page it should display, Check out 1st page i.e. result.php source code weather its correct?

Comment: Thanks Sumant 4 ur time..I manage to do it when using another calendar script..I think the previous prob was under the calendar itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:-

Put below sript under head in Result.php

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" title="Style CSS" href="cwcalendar.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="calendar.js"></script>
```

Add below code under body in Result.php

```
     $date="date[".$i."]"; 
echo "<input type='text' name='date[$i]' id='$date' value=' ' onclick=\"fPopCalendar('".$date."')\">";
```

script reference:
http://codetale.com/2009/06/21/javascript-calendar-widget-108/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this line:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='retDate[$i]' value='$retDate'/>";
```

to be:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='retDate[$i]' value='$rDate'/>";
```

because $rDate is where you have actually stored the return date that you fetched from the database:

```
$rDate = $row['ReturnDate'];
```

Comment: thanks john, but it's still didn't display the date. it's display 1000

Comment: oh, and you might want to copy the hidden input into the else statement in result.php, inside of the td